# How to have multiple home pages and common inner pages

Tags: php

I've designed a site for my client in PHP and MySQL. They have branches in different countries, and need a separate site for each country. The sites will be identical except for the home page. Since the inner pages will be constantly updated, I want to maintain only one copy of the inner pages which will be shared by all the websites. So, the homepages will reside on different domains, and share the inner pages that reside in one common place. How do I achieve this?

Comment: if( $country=='uk') show_homepage('uk')

Comment: common CMS use case.
What have you tried?

Comment: No, I don't wish to use any CMS. Just raw PHP. Moreover, each home page needs to reside in its own respective domain, and still access the inner pages stored at a common location.